# Create C struct representing module with pointer to string and float arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I am working on the following question:

> Write ‘C’ code that defines a structured type called moduleStruct with
>   members that store the name of the module as a character array, the number of
>   students taking the module as an integer, the names of the students taking the
>   module as a pointer to an array of strings and the results for the students stored as an array of floats.

I am unsure how to have a float array in the struct without knowing student number, so I just assumed they meant pointer to float array.

This is what I made:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct mS{
    char name[50];
    int studentNum;
    char (*studentNames)[50];
    float *studentGrades;
}moduleStruct;

void deleteModule(moduleStruct* ms);
void deleteModule(moduleStruct* ms){
    free(ms->studentNames);
    free(ms->studentGrades);
    free(ms);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   moduleStruct* m1 = malloc(sizeof(moduleStruct));

    strcpy(m1->name, "Programming");

    m1 -> studentNum = 5;

    char students[][50]  = {"Alan", "Bob", "Charles", "James", "Peter"};
    m1 -> studentNames = malloc(sizeof(students));
    memcpy(m1 -> studentNames, &students, sizeof(students));

    float grades[5]= {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5};
    m1->studentGrades = malloc(sizeof(grades));
    memcpy(m1->studentGrades, grades, sizeof(grades));

    printf("%s\n", m1->name);
    printf("%d\n", m1->studentNum);
    printf("%s\n", m1->studentNames[2]);
    printf("%f\n", m1->studentGrades[4]);

    deleteModule(m1);

    printf("%s\n", m1->name);
    return 0;
}
```

So I have 3 questions:

1. Is there a way to use a float array directly without knowing student number?
2. How to improve this solution?
3. Is there a way where I dont have to pre-define max name size in studentNames?

Comment: `x = malloc(...); x = somethingelse;` is a memory leak,  you forget about the malloc block and point your pointer at the somethingelse. Instead you probably want to copy the data from the original place into the heap storage

Comment: @M.M edited code, can you please check it?

Comment: you still do the same problem with `heapStudents`. Also `float studentGrades[];` should be `float *studentGrades;` , for the way you are using it anyway

Comment: @M.M yeah, sorry for that. I forgot to edit those. Is there a way to work with string array without deciding the max size in the struct?

Answer (score 1):

Right off the bat:

```
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:32:14: warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 2 has type 'float *' [-Wformat=]
   32 |     printf("%f\n", m1->studentGrades);
      |             ~^     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |              |       |
      |              double  float *
main.c:32:14: warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 2 has type 'float *' [-Wformat=]
```

So let's fix it to print the value. `printf("%f\n", *m1->studentGrades);`

```
Programming
5
Alan
1.100000
```

That's better.

---

```c
char* heapStudents = malloc(sizeof(students));
heapStudents = *students;
m1 -> studentNames = heapStudents;
```

That doesn't seem right. Let's see what's happening.

```
Breakpoint 2, main () at main.c:19
19          char students[][20]  = {"Alan", "Bob", "Charles", "James", "Peter"};
(gdb) s
20          char* heapStudents = malloc(sizeof(students));
(gdb) p students
$5 = {"Alan", '\000' <repeats 15 times>, "Bob", '\000' <repeats 16 times>, "Charles", '\000' <repeats 12 times>,
  "James", '\000' <repeats 14 times>, "Peter", '\000' <repeats 14 times>}
(gdb) x students
0x22fdd0:       0x6e616c41
(gdb) s
21          heapStudents = *students;
(gdb) s
22          m1 -> studentNames = heapStudents;
(gdb) p *heapStudents
$8 = 65 'A'
(gdb) x heapStudents
0x22fdd0:       0x6e616c41
```

You allocate an array of character arrays on the stack (at 0x6e616c41). Then you allocate the same amount of memory on the heap, and save the pointer to it as `*heapStudents`. Then you overwrite the pointer with the "address" equal to the value of the decayed pointer to the 0th element in the `students` character array, leaking the `malloc`'d memory in the process. Oops.

Let's fix that.

```c
m1->studentNames = malloc(sizeof(students));
memcpy(m1->studentNames, &students, sizeof(students));
```

Now we allocate the memory and assign the `*studentNames` pointer in the struct pointed to by `m1` to point to the address returned by `malloc`. Then we copy the stack array to the allocated memory on the heap. We haven't leaked any memory, because we can call `free(m1->studentNames)` later on.

---

The same fix must be applied for `studentGrades`. But let's try something different; allocating memory on the heap without first allocating an array on the stack.

```c
m1->studentGrades = malloc(sizeof(float[5]));
m1->studentGrades[0] = 1.1;
m1->studentGrades[1] = 2.2;
m1->studentGrades[2] = 3.3;
m1->studentGrades[3] = 4.4;
m1->studentGrades[4] = 5.5;
```

Notice that we can use array indexing with a `float* studentGrades` pointer.

---

Onto the questions proper:

> Is there a way to use a float array directly without knowing student number?

Without knowing the maximum number of students, you can `#define MAX_STUDENTS 100` to initialise your arrays, then use `m1->studentNum` to iterate. Or, skip allocating on the stack and just use `malloc(m1->studentNum * sizeof(var))`/`calloc(m1->studentNum, sizeof(var));`.

Alternatively, use `realloc` as and when required.

> How to access second student name?

Alter your struct definition so you have an array of pointers which point to character arrays. `char* studentNames[20];` to have 20 pointers then store your data in a location on the heap, and save the pointer in the array member of the struct:

```c
m1->studentNames[0] = strcpy(calloc(20, sizeof(char)), "Alan");
m1->studentNames[1] = strcpy(calloc(20, sizeof(char)), "Bob");
m1->studentNames[2] = strcpy(calloc(20, sizeof(char)), "Charles");
m1->studentNames[3] = strcpy(calloc(20, sizeof(char)), "James");
m1->studentNames[4] = strcpy(calloc(20, sizeof(char)), "Peter");
```

Use `printf("%s\n", m1->studentNames[1]);` to print "Bob". etc.

Alternatively, use a double pointer in the struct and have it point to an array of pointers on the heap. This way to can dynamically allocate the memory above the 20-element limit.

> How to properly set pointer to float array and access each member?

If you have `float studentGrades[20];` in the struct, you can make a pointer like this

```c
float *p = &m1->studentGrades[0];
printf("%f %f\n", p[0], p[1]); // prints 1.100000 2.200000
```

---

Altogether:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct mS{
    char name[50];
    int studentNum;
    char* studentNames[20];
    float studentGrades[20];
} moduleStruct;

int main(void) {
    moduleStruct *m1 = malloc(sizeof(moduleStruct));

    strcpy(m1->name, "Programming");

    m1->studentNum = 5;

    //char students[][20]  = {"Alan", "Bob", "Charles", "James", "Peter"};
    m1->studentNames[0] = strcpy(calloc(20, sizeof(char)), "Alan");
    m1->studentNames[1] = strcpy(calloc(20, sizeof(char)), "Bob");
    m1->studentNames[2] = strcpy(calloc(20, sizeof(char)), "Charles");
    m1->studentNames[3] = strcpy(calloc(20, sizeof(char)), "James");
    m1->studentNames[4] = strcpy(calloc(20, sizeof(char)), "Peter");

    /*float grades[5] = {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5};
    m1->studentGrades = malloc(sizeof(grades));
    memcpy(m1->studentGrades, &grades, sizeof(grades));*/

    //m1->studentGrades[0] = malloc(sizeof(float[5]));
    m1->studentGrades[0] = 1.1;
    m1->studentGrades[1] = 2.2;
    m1->studentGrades[2] = 3.3;
    m1->studentGrades[3] = 4.4;
    m1->studentGrades[4] = 5.5;

    printf("%s\n", m1->name);
    printf("%d\n", m1->studentNum);
    printf("%s\n", m1->studentNames[0]);
    printf("%f\n", m1->studentGrades[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

---

EDIT

> So I have 2 questions:

(Questions 0 to 2 maybe, but I definately see 3!)

> Is there a way to use a float array directly without knowing student number?

See above.

> How to improve this solution?

Aside from removing the `implicit declaration of function 'deleteModule'`?
See below.

> Is there a way where I dont have to pre-define max name size in studentNames?

Have the struct contain a pointer to an array of pointers. `realloc` this array every time you add a student. Assign one of the pointers in the array to point at a `malloc`'d character array to store the student name.

```c
typedef struct mS{
    // ...
    char **studentNames;
}
// ...
char str[] = "Alan";
m1->studentNames = realloc(m1->studentNames, ++(m1->studentNum)*sizeof(*m1->studentNames);
m1->studentNames[m1->studentNum-1] = strcpy(calloc(strlen(str)+1, sizeof(char)), str);
```

5 bytes are allocated to store the name, and the size of a pointer (probably 8B) is added onto `m1->studentNames`'s space to store the address of the name.

Comment: What if there is more than a 100 students? Wont that cause issues? I edited my question code to use some the tips you provided. I kept the stack arrays mainly because they seem more convenient to use in case there are a large number of students (rather than assign student one by one to m1->studentNames). I also added a deleteModule function. I used float pointer as it seems more appropriate for storing unknown number of grades.

Comment: The point is to define `MAX_STUDENTS` to be greater than you would ever need. The solution is to avoid the stack and allocate everything dynamically (on the heap). You're unlikely to define a large number of students because they would be added one at a time (with a function?) from a file/stdin/etc rather than hardcoded into the program.

Answer (score 0):

You would have 2 approach:

1. either assume that module would have a maximum capacity ( quite realistic, but probably not what is desired for the exercise )
2. Dynamically allocated arrays, in which you allocate as needed

## Maximum (fixed) capacity

```
#define moduleCapacity 200
#define moduleMaxName 50

struct moduleStruct {
    char name[moduleMaxName];
    unsigned int studentsCount;
    const char *studentsName[moduleCapacity];
    float studentsGrade[moduleCapacity];
};
```

```
void populateModule(
    struct moduleStruct *target,
    const char *moduleName,
    const unsigned int studentsCount,
    const char* studentsName[],
    const float studentsGrade[]) {

    strncpy(target->name, moduleName, moduleMaxName);
    target->studentsCount = studentsCount;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < studentsCount; ++i) {
       if(i >= moduleCapacity) return; // student over the limit are thrown away, sorry first come first served basis
       target->studentsName[i] = studentsName[i];
       target->studentsGrade[i] = studentsGrade[i];
    }
}

void printModule(struct moduleStruct *input) {
    printf("name : %s\n", input->name);
    printf("students : %i\n", input->studentsCount);
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < input->studentsCount; ++i) {
        printf("%u %s %f\n", i+1, input->studentsName[i], input->studentsGrade[i]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    struct moduleStruct m1;
    const char *names[] = {"Alan", "Bob", "Charles", "James", "Peter"};
    const float grades[] = {1.1f, 2.2f, 3.3f, 4.4f, 5.5f};
    populateModule(
        &m1,
        "Programming",
        5,
        names,
        grades
    );
    printModule(&m1);
}
```

## Dynamically allocated arrays

```
#define moduleMaxName 50

struct moduleStruct {
    char name[moduleMaxName];
    unsigned int studentsCount;
    const char **studentsName;
    float *studentsGrade;
};


void populateModule(
    struct moduleStruct *target,
    const char *moduleName,
    const unsigned int studentsCount,
    const char* studentsName[],
    const float studentsGrade[]) {

    strncpy(target->name, moduleName, moduleMaxName);
    target->studentsCount = studentsCount;
    // we have the student count, we can allocate an array that is sized just for the class size
    target->studentsName = calloc(target->studentsCount, sizeof(char*)); 
    target->studentsGrade = calloc(target->studentsCount, sizeof(float));
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < studentsCount; ++i) {
       target->studentsName[i] = studentsName[i];
       target->studentsGrade[i] = studentsGrade[i];
    }
}

// printModule & main remain the same
```